# *I had this type of error in my project build, how to solve?*

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

**Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)**

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions suggested in the error? you have been given 3 solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of gradle related issues sometimes get solved by using invalidate cache & restart. Just give it a try. Click on File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart. A pop up will come (choose invalidate and restart). After this it will take some time to build up your project. Just give it a try.